# How to disable tooltips for an entire .net DataGridView column

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, tooltip

I have a winform datagridview which contains a column of buttons. I'd like to disable tooltips for that column only -- tooltips should still show up for other columns. I find tooltips get in the way of clicking the button -- when one clicks on the tooltip, the click event doesn't percolate down to the button. Very annoying.

I've tried handling the CellTooltipNeeded event and return null or empty string for that column, but then the tooltip just reverts to showing the button text in the tooltip. I've also tried setting the Column.ToolTipText to empty string, and that correctly hides the column header's tooltip, but all the other rows' tooltip still shows up.

What's the best way to disable tooltips for an entire column?

Thanks
Jimmy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was looking for an answer to this question but all forums stated it was not possible.  However, I did find a solution.

On your DataGridView, handle the CellMouseEnter event.  In the event handler the `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` contains a ColumnIndex property.  Use that to set the `DataGridView.ShowCellToolTips` property.  Like this (Excuse the VB please):

```
Private Sub MyDataGridView_CellMouseEnter(sender As Object, e as DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView.CellMouseEnter
    MyDataGridView.ShowCellToolTips = e.ColumnIndex = <the Column # I want to show Tooltips>
End Sub
```

And, obviously, it's very straightforward to turn this on or off at the cell level too since `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` also contains a `RowIndex` property.

I'm only sorry I discovered an answer five years after this was posted!

Answer (score 1):

Does setting it to a space get you where you want?  Otherwise, try a dot or something really tiny.

Comment: Interesting work-around :) It doesn't get me all the way, as a tooltip still shows up... but it's better than having the full button text.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work for me. When setting it to space or `String.Empty` it will stay on its old value. :/

Comment: @C4ud3x That is why she said setting it to a space or a period, not String.Empty. However, there now seems to be a better answer from Mark K which I will test shortly.

Comment: @C4ud3x: Mark K's approach works fine; please also see my c# method.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Mark K's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37278861/68936), here is a static method that can be used to hide tooltips for button columns, and show them for other columns (including column & row headers).

```
    public static void CellMouseEnterHandlerToHideTooltipsForButtonColumns(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataGridView grid = sender as DataGridView;
            grid.ShowCellToolTips = (e.RowIndex < 0) || (e.ColumnIndex < 0) || !(grid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
    }
```